# C++ get child process id from parent process id

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-10, createprocess

In windows 10, if i create a process to open calc.exe first its trigger calc.exe and exit that process after that it opens calculator.exe. How can i get actual process id that shows in task manager.
i am using following code to create the process and display process id

```
if(!CreateProcess(("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\calc.exe"),
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
FALSE,
0,
NULL,
NULL,
&startup_info,
&pi) )
{
 args.GetReturnValue().Set(Nan::New(response).ToLocalChecked());
}
else
{

int dwPid = GetProcessId(pi.hProcess);
int v = dwPid->Int32Value();
args.GetReturnValue().Set(dwPid);
}
```

Comment: use fork() method

Comment: @JerryGoyal `fork` is a POSIX function, generally not available on Windows (where it can be emulated using `CreateProcess`).

Comment: Have you checked `dwPid`? Is it not correct? What value (for example) do `GetProcessId` return, and what value did you expect?

Comment: yes dwpid showing the process id of calc.exe from that it detaches calculator.exe i need that process id of detached calculator.exe

Comment: Also, what did you expect `dwPid->Int32Value()` to do? The variable `dwPid` is already an `int` value. And as a value of a primitive type it doesn't have member functions. And it's most definitely isn't a pointer.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "detached"? The `CreateProcess` function creates a process running separately from yours. It already is "detached" (as I see it).

Comment: i am returnbing this value to a node js function call thats y i convert it itnot Int32value

Comment: detached process is something like parent process creates child process

Comment: i have a powershell code i am looking for a c++ code similar to this Get-WmiObject win32_process | where {$_.ParentProcessId -eq 17804 -and $_.ProcessName -ne 'conhost.exe' } |select processid,ProcessName

Comment: you create process `A` which exec process `B` and exit. you ask how get `PID` of `B`. we can enumerate processes and compare `PROCESSENTRY32.th32ParentProcessID` with `PIDa` (need not close handle of `A` process for hold it `PIDa` ) - so in this way we got the `PIDb`. but what if `B` exec `C` and then also exit. and actual calc is `C` or just `A` actual calc ?

Comment: And that's exactly what [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) *does!* The process calling `CreateProcess` will become the parent process, and the new process is the child process. And the child process is running separately from the parent process. So I don't see what the problem is. Maybe it has nothing to do with the `CreateProcess` function, but with something else? Like e.g. how you "return" the value to Node?

Comment: ok you mean the child process is running entirely separate from parent.any link or trace ?

Comment: As far as I can remember (from a previous question wanting to enumerate a processes children), a process / the system doesn't track child processes (of a process), only a process' parent. You would -- I think -- have to enumerate process IDs and chase parent processes back to the one you want (which presumably is what the PS script does) but you'd have to do it before the CALC.EXE terminates (by which time there'd be no connection to your process).

Comment: @TripeHound - `but you'd have to do it before the CALC.EXE terminates ` - no, until we keep process handle even to terminated process it `PID` still valid. so we can search for it child's by this `PID`

Comment: and for what you cal `GetProcessId(pi.hProcess);` ?!? when you already have `PID` in`pi.dwProcessId`. look like close `pi.hProcess` and `pi.hThread` you even not try

Comment: @RbMm You can keep a  handle to a terminated process (so you can examine it's exit code, etc.) but I _suspect_ (but admit I don't know for certain) that once CALC.EXE has terminated, CALCULATOR.EXE will no longer show that PID as its parent.

Comment: @RbMm for pi.dwProcessId i am getting this error "cannot convert argument 1 from 'DWORD' to 'HANDLE" and pi.hProcess  i am getting 0 as return value

Comment: @TripeHound - you are wrong. `PID` is freed when `EPROCESS` structure in kernel destroyed - it destroyed when no more reference to it. until we keep handle(reference) to process - `EPROCESS` and it `PID` (`UniqueProcessId` field in `EPROCESS` still valid. this  *exactly*. parent process `ID' also stored in `EPROCESS` - `InheritedFromUniqueProcessId` and already never changed

Comment: @sandeepks - what you trying to do ? `pi.dwProcessId` is`PID` of process which you create. if you need `PID` you need use exactly this field. `and pi.hProcess i am getting 0` ? if `createprocess` return `true` - `pi.hProcess  != 0`

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <cstring>

#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

vector<DWORD> pids_from_ppid(DWORD ppid) {
  vector<DWORD> pids;
  HANDLE hp = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  PROCESSENTRY32 pe = { 0 };
  pe.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
  if (Process32First(hp, &pe)) {
    do {
      if (pe.th32ParentProcessID == ppid) {
        pids.push_back(pe.th32ProcessID);
      }
    } while (Process32Next(hp, &pe));
  }
  CloseHandle(hp);
  return pids;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
  if (arc >= 2) {
    DWORD ppid = (DWORD)strtoul(argv[1], nullptr, 10);
    vector<DWORD> pidVec = pids_from_ppid(ppid);
    for (int i = 0; i < pidVec.size(); i++) {
      cout << pidVec[i] << endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```